# categorical property: every morphism can be decomposed into an epimorphism and monomorphism

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Certain categories have the property that for every morphism $f:A\to B$ can be decomposed into an epimorphism and monomorphism. with some intermediate object $C$. e.g. **Grp** has this property.

Is there a name for this so I can look it up?

Comment: cf. [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28epi%2C+mono%29+factorization+system) e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most commonly such factorizations exist where the epimorphism is even regular; in most interesting categories not every epi is regular. A category with nice (regular epi,mono) factorizations is, fittingly, called a *regular category.*

The key property making these factorization systems interesting is that every regular epi is “left orthogonal” to every mono. Orthogonal factorization systems are very interesting in their own right, as are their weakenings which play a central role in homotopical algebra. In exceptionally special categories like groups and sets, arbitrary epimorphisms manage to be left orthogonal to monos, and that is the situation described at Henno’s link.

Comment: Your description of exact categories is incorrect. Whenever a regular epimorphism has a kernel pair, it is the coequalizer of that kernel pair, and regular categories are finitely complete. The defining property of exact categories is more the opposite : every equivalence relation is a kernel pair (and in fact, the kernel pair of its coequalizer).

Comment: @ArnaudD Thanks; I meant to say “more or less”, but even that is not true.